# 'HTTP Error 429 Too Many Requests' using Google Perspective API saying

Tags: python, google-api, http-status-code-429

I am using the following code to identify how toxic comments in a data frame are. But I keep getting the 'HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests'. What should I do?

```
def aggressiveLanguage_mapper(input_data):

  key = "my_key"
  p = PerspectiveAPI(key)

  input_data['insult_prob'] = np.nan
  input_data['toxicity_prob'] = np.nan
  input_data['threat_prob'] = np.nan

  ignore_comments_counter = 0
  j = 0

  #additional code to resolve an error
  type_base = type(input_data['parent_id'].iloc[0])

  for ind, row in input_data.iterrows():
    j += 1
    if j % 60 == 0:
      time.sleep(15)
      print('finished comment '+str(j)+'/'+str(len(input_data)))

    curr_author = row['author']
    curr_subreddit_id = row['subreddit_id']
    curr_id = row['id']
    curr_comment_body = row['body']
    
    #check the aggressive language probability in the comment body
    result = p.score(curr_comment_body, ["INSULT","TOXICITY","THREAT"])
    input_data.at[ind,'insult_prob'] = result["INSULT"]
    input_data.at[ind,'toxicity_prob'] = result["TOXICITY"]
    input_data.at[ind,'threat_prob'] = result["THREAT"]
    #time.sleep(5)

  print('total number of comments ignored: ' +str(ignore_comments_counter))
  return input_data
```

Comment: Send no more than one request per second.

Comment: Yes, I figured it out. By restricting the number of requests to no more than 100 per 100 sec (or 1 per 1 sec) it worked.